# Is there a way in R to create a character vector with the bounds of some intervals from a vector with the breakpoints?

Tags: r

I am relatively new to R programming and have been several days dealing with the following puzzle. Is there a way to create a character vector containing the bounds of intervals from a vector where you have provided the breakpoints of the intervals?

Let me provide you an example. Imagine I have the following vector:

```
a <- c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1)
```

and from this one I want to create

```
b <- c("0 - 0.2", "0.2 - 0.4", "0.4 - 0.6", "0.6 - 0.8", "0.8 - 1")
```

I have been trying several things but have been unable to obtain any results.

Comment: maybe at some point you'll need `cut` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `paste` with `head` and `tail`

```
b <- paste(head(a, -1), tail(a, -1), sep = "-")
b
#[1] "0-0.2"   "0.2-0.4" "0.4-0.6" "0.6-0.8" "0.8-1"
```

Or using indexing

```
b <- paste(a[-length(a)], a[-1], sep = "-")
```

Comment: `gsub("\\(|\\]", "", sub(",", " \\- ", levels(cut(NaN, breaks=a))))` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

An option is `lag` with `str_c`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
b <- str_c(lag(a), a, sep="-")[-1]
b
#[1] "0-0.2"   "0.2-0.4" "0.4-0.6" "0.6-0.8" "0.8-1"
```